# Why does konsole switch its icon and how to avoid?

Tags: konsole

When firing up konsole, the window shows the following application icon in the upper left corner:

[image: konsole app icon at startup]

After pressing the TAB key (which triggers filename completion in bash), konsole switches its application icon to the following:

[image: konsole app icon after TAB]

Why does konsole switch its icon and how can I prevent that? The second icon is difficult to identify in the task list.

Using Arch Linux, LXDE with openbox, konsole 19.08.0.
The second icon seems to be a placeholder icon. I see it in various other unrelated places.